# rails-opal and opal ujs on remote: true

Tags: ruby, opalrb

I use `rails-opal`, opal-jquery gems, also require `opal-ujs` in application.js.rb, BUT on for example `link_to "Foo", some_path, remote:true` if I render e.g. `remote_reply.js.rb layout:false` with `puts HI` that code is not executed on client. If I send `remote_reply.js` with `alert('foo');` all works fine? Is this only my problem, or such thing is unsupported? p.s. everywhere else opal works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will face that issue: you should render js file with `.opal` extension like `remote_reply.js.opal` and that will do.